# URL variable use in PHP array (wordpress related)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, url, variables

I got very crazy with this tricky question. My url is: www.mysite.com/page/?id=sun

I would like to get the variable (sun) and put it into my PHP array:

```
<?php 
 $tag = $_GET['id'];

 wp_reset_query();

 query_posts(array('post_type'=> 'projects','technologiestags'=> $tag) );
 if(have_posts()):
 while(have_posts()):the_post();
 ?>

 <div class="technology">
 <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4><br/><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(''); ?></a>

</br></br><div class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&nbsp;&raquo;</a></div>

</div><!--END of technology Id-->

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

As you can see I used " **. echo "$tag" .** ", and it doesn't work. Is there any other way how I can get the URL variable and insert it into PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is indeed your full source, keep in mind that `if():` and `while():` (the colon notation) _require_ closing `endif`/`endwhile` statements. If you really want a single statement body, remove the colons.

Comment: Hi lanzz, the full code is:

    <?php 
    $tag = $_GET['id'];

    wp_reset_query();

    query_posts(array('post_type'=> 'projects','technologiestags'=> $tag) );
    if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="technology">
    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4><br/><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(''); ?></a>

    </br></br><div class="readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&nbsp;&raquo;</a></div>

    </div><!--END of technology Id-->

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

Comment: Uh, very helpful. Consider editing it in your question.

Comment: sorry I have add the full code into the main question box on the top...

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts(array('post_type'=> 'projects','technologiestags' => $tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

$tag is a variable and can be used instead of passing a string:

```
query_posts(array('post_type'=> 'projects','technologiestags' => $tag);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot still no luck. Got an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')' in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-php-widget/wp-php-widget.php(52) : eval()'d code on line 7

Comment: Just add another closing parenthesis before the semicolon to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes, try:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])):
        $tag = stript_tags($_GET['id']);
        wp_reset_query();
        query_posts(array(
                'post_type'=> 'projects',
                'technologiestags'=> $tag)
        );
        if(have_posts()):
            while(have_posts()):
                the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="technology">
                    <h4><?= the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <div class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?= the_post_thumbnail(''); ?></a></div>
                    <div class="readmore"><a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&nbsp;&raquo;</a></div>
                </div>
                <?
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
        endif;
    endif;
```

Comment: Hi NeoMacuser, unfortunately I got no luck - the erro is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')'